# Error says function requires 1 parameter when it actually requires none

Tags: unity-game-engine, sendmessage

In a Unity scene I want two objects to communicate via SendMessage so I don't have to do GetComponent at runtime.

Here is the SendMessage call:

```
 hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("OnSelect", SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
```

And on another object (called Button) I have a script with this function:

```
 public void OnSelect()
     {
         dialogueManager.DisplayDialogue(this);
     }
```

When I play the game the OnSelect function runs without any problem and does everything it needs to do, but the console gives me the error 'Failed to call function OnSelect of class Button; Calling function with no parameters but the function requires 1.'

Why does it say the function requires 1 parameter when it actually requires none? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try removing `SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver` parameter, does the error still exist?

Comment: @Bingostew yes it still exists, both if I put DontRequireReceiver and if I ramove the parameter completely

Comment: Then can you post the entire class for Button?

Comment: `so I don't have to do GetComponent at runtime.` Note that using `GetComponent` is quite fast in newer versions since it now uses a Hash ... on the other side `SendMessage` is and will always be **much slower** then using `GetComponent`! Why? Well first of all working with strings is always slow and then it is send to all attached `MonoBehaviour`s and has to parse whether the according method exists there .... You should really simply stick to `hit.transform.GetComponent<Button>().OnSelect();` and make sure you are using **your** `Button` and not `UnityEngine.UI.Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Unity's button class does already contain a function named "OnSelect" which does take one parameter. You can rename your function to something different https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnSelect.html
2. SendMessageOptions should be the third parameter not the second. So the syntax should be something like:
   `hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("OnCustomHit", null, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);`
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html